# finding least subset in an rdd in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

can anyone help me
I have an RDD of BitSets like

```
Array[scala.collection.mutable.BitSet] = Array(BitSet(1, 2), BitSet(1, 7), BitSet(8, 9, 10, 11), BitSet(1, 2, 3, 4),BitSet(8,9,10),BitSet(1,2,3))
```

I want rdd of `(BitSet(1,2),BitSet(1,7),BitSet(8,9,10))`
that is i require least subset or the BitSet which is not subset to any BitSet

Explanation:
here `(1,2),(1,2,3)(1,2,3,4)` -----here least subset is `(1,2)` and
`(1,7)` is not subset to other BitSets ---so `(1,7)` also present in the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved using aggregation

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(BitSet(1, 2),
      BitSet(1, 7),
      BitSet(8, 9, 10, 11),
      BitSet(1, 2, 3, 4),
      BitSet(8, 9, 10),
      BitSet(1, 2, 3)))
val result = rdd.aggregate(Seq[BitSet]())(accumulate, merge)
println(result)
```

output:

```
List(BitSet(8, 9, 10), BitSet(1, 7), BitSet(1, 2))
```

`accumulate` is a function that collects data on each spark partition

```
def accumulate(acc: Seq[BitSet], elem: BitSet): Seq[BitSet] = {
  val subsets = acc.filterNot(elem.subsetOf)
  if (notSuperSet(subsets)(elem)) elem +: subsets else subsets
}
```

`merge` combines results of partitions

```
def merge(left: Seq[BitSet], right: Seq[BitSet]): Seq[BitSet] = {
  val leftSubsets = left.filter(notSuperSet(right))
  val rightSubsets = right.filter(notSuperSet(leftSubsets))
  leftSubsets ++ rightSubsets
}
```

and a helper function `notSuperSet` that is a predicate to check whether a new set is superset of other sets

```
def notSuperSet(subsets: Seq[BitSet])(set: BitSet): Boolean =
  subsets.forall(!_.subsetOf(set))
```

Comment: Great illustration of `aggregate`, especially the use of terms `accumulate` and `merge` – far better to understand than `seqOp` and `combOp` in the official method signature.

Comment: Is it possible to get the output of accumulate method of each partition without merge operation in aggregate@Nazarii Bardiuk

Comment: No. But `rdd.mapPartitions(_.foldLeft(Seq[BitSet]())(accumulate).iterator)` will perform accumulation per partition, each partition will have only least subsets. To debug locally you can try to run `rdd.foreachPartition(it => println(it.toList))`